# Check if all property values are the same in an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects all with the same property name with isReady. I want to fire up a function when all objects isReady property is true.

```
let players = [
 0: {isReady: true}, 
 1: {isReady: false}, 
 2: {isReady: true}
]
```

Should return false

```
let players = [
 0: {isReady: true}, 
 1: {isReady: true}, 
 2: {isReady: true}
]
```

Should return true

```
for(let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  if(players[i].isReady === true) {
    startGame()
  }
}
```

I've tried to loop all objects but the if statement returns true if even if 1 object has a true value.

Comment: `players.every(player => player.isReady)`

Comment: When are the same? or when all are TRUE?

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this in two ways

1-  By using array inbuilt method every which will return boolean after checking full array.
Example-

```
let players = [
{isReady: true}, 
 {isReady: true}, 
  {isReady: true}]
const isPlayersReady = players.every(data=> data.isReady)
if(isPlayersReady ){
startGame()
}
```

2- By using the Set data structure

```
let result = players.map(a => a.isReady);
console.log(new Set(result).size === 1); // True
```